# UV's not the same in substance painter

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I have a game-ready revolver i want to bake normals with, I prefer substance painter for baking normals. So here are my UV's (low poly only) in blender:

[image]

Then after exporting my revolver as a .obj file, and importing into SP, here is what i get:
[image]

Also, when I left click and hold parts of my object disapear. Here it is before left clicking:
[image]

Here it is after left clicking:
[image]

I UV-unwrapped every part of my revolver, yet 90% of my UV's are missing. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it turned out since i had two materials it was seperating them by "texture sets" which made part of my UV's disapear. So instead i deleted both my materials, added a new one, and baked.